# PHP cut a paragraph

Tags: php

I have a paragraph :

> **Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad mini**m veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.

I want to show only 140 character (I emboldened the 140 character above). So I use `substr()` function in PHP:

```
 echo substr($str, 0, 140); // let say $str contain the paragraph above
```

As you can see above in the text, It cut the "minim" word into "mini" !!, if that's an English word, let say "Singular", and it suddenly cut info "Sing", it will have a different meaning and will make the entire sentence nonsense.

So I decide to cut the last sentence and there would not be any weird word resulting from the `substr()` function.

Anybody know how to cut the last sentences after `substr()`?

Comment: you want cut sentence after final word ? as minim ?

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10254260/how-to-truncate-a-string-in-php-to-the-sentence-closest-to-a-certain-number-of-c)

Comment: basically you will need to **(1)** check if the current sub-string is ended properly (the next character [141] is a dot)  **(2)**  if you are not o.k, use `strpos` to search for the next dot character **(3)** append a new sub-string from letter 141 to the found dot char

Comment: as @AbdoAdel said, check if character is space or dot or find closest one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few approaches to this, I suppose. The easiest one that comes to mind is exploding the string in words, removing the last one, and then imploding them again, as follows:

```
$str = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";
if (strlen($str) > 140)
{
    $str = substr($str, 0, 140);
    $str = explode(' ', $str);
    array_pop($str); // remove last word from array
    $str = implode(' ', $str);
}
```

So this should result in:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad

You can also include `...` to the string to give a sense of continuity with:

```
$str = $str . ' ...';
```

Comment: plus one for `$str = $str . ' ...';`

Comment: Oh no no no no, what i meant is, cut the ENTIRE last sentence ~ not just the last non-sense word.

Comment: Well, you can cut in ponctuation instead of spaces. If you want something more gramatical it will require a whole lot more intelligent script.