# PHP limit the number of words from a string

Tags: php

I have been using a function I found here at StackOverflow from another answer elsewhere. While the function helps me and does what I want, sometimes the result isn't accurate. (credits to the author I don't remember the link)

```
function truncate ($str, $length) {
    if (strlen($str) > $length) {
        $str = substr($str, 0, $length+1);
        $pos = strrpos($str, ' ');
        $str = substr($str, 0, ($pos > 0)? $pos : $length);
    }
    return $str;
}
```

That is the function I am using. However, sometimes it cuts off after a period which the paragraph ends up making no sense. For example, it ends like this:

```
It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia is an American comedy series about four friends in their late 20s with clear sociopathic tendencies who run an unsuccessful Irish bar, "Paddy's Pub," in South Philadelphia. The
```

I would like to end like this:

```
It's Always Sunny in Philadelphia is an American comedy series about four friends in their late 20s with clear sociopathic tendencies who run an unsuccessful Irish bar, "Paddy's Pub," in South Philadelphia.
```

I want it to cut after the closest period; regardless I set it to cut after 200 words. Even if it ends up cutting at the 190th word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to truncate a string in PHP to the sentence closest to a certain number of characters?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10254414/5447994)

Comment: thanks, i will try that answer, should i delete my question? since is a duplicate. idk how stackoverflow works.

Comment: No issues, but make sure to surf before posting a question. SO almost have answers for all beginner level questions.